# Join on 3 tables insanely slow on giant tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a query which goes like this:

```
SELECT    insanlyBigTable.description_short, 
          insanlyBigTable.id AS insanlyBigTable, 
          insanlyBigTable.type AS insanlyBigTableLol, 
          catalogpartner.id AS catalogpartner_id
FROM insanlyBigTable
INNER JOIN smallerTable ON smallerTable.id = insanlyBigTable.catalog_id
INNER JOIN smallerTable1 ON smallerTable1.catalog_id = smallerTable.id 
  AND smallerTable1.buyer_id = 'xxx'
WHERE smallerTable1.cont = 'Y' AND insanlyBigTable.type IN ('111','222','33') 
GROUP BY smallerTable.id;
```

Now, when I run the query first time it copies the giant table into a temp table... I want to know how I can prevent that? I am considering a nested query, or even to reverse the join (not sure the effect would be to run faster), but that is well, not nice. Any other suggestions?

Comment: why do you have a GROUP BY clause and no aggregate functions?

Comment: Do you have an index on `insanlyBigTable.type`?

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions, the use of a GROUP BY clause is inappropriate (and, possibly, inefficient)

Comment: Can you post actual query that runs with execution plan and some index and table information? As you have notice this query has no agg, function but has group by clause.

Comment: How many rows is insanely big? How many rows are returned by the simple where clause `insanlyBigTable.type IN ('111','222','33')`

Comment: What does your query execution plan look like?  That's always the first thing you should look at when trying to diagnose query performance issues.

Comment: No idea for the group by clausule. it is a engine generated query, execution plan is second step copying into temp table... it gets stuck there for 4 minutes. The query is the actuall query only with names replaced.

Comment: Insanly big is 1.7gb big table, not database.... so yea any kind of work with is..... bad..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To figure out how to optimize your query, we first have to boil down exactly what it is selecting so that we can preserve that information while we change things around.

### What your query does

So, it looks like we need the following

- The GROUP BY clause limits the results to at most one row per `catalog_id`
- `smallerTable1.cont = 'Y'`, `insanelyBigTable.type IN ('111','222','33')`, and `buyer_id = 'xxx'` appear to be the filters on the query.
- And we want data from `insanlyBigTable` and ... `catalogpartner`? I would guess that `catalogpartner` is smallerTable1, due to the `id` of `smallerTable` being linked to the `catalog_id` of the other tables.

I'm not sure on what the purpose of including the `buyer_id` filter on the `ON` clause was for, but unless you tell me differently, I'll assume the fact it is on the `ON` clause is unimportant.

### The point of the query

I am unsure about the intent of the query, based on that GROUP BY statement. You will obtain just one row per `catalog_id` in the `insanelyBigTable`, but you don't appear to care *which* row it is. Indeed, the fact that you can run this query at all is due to a [special non-standard feature in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html) that lets you SELECT columns that do not appear in the GROUP BY statement... however, you don't get to select WHICH columns. This means you could have information from 4 different rows for each of your selected items.

My best guess, based on column names, is that you are trying to bring back a list of items that are in the same catalog as something that was purchased by a given buyer, but without any more than one item per catalog. In addition, you want something to connect back to the purchased item in that catalog, via the `catalogpartner` table's `id`.

So, something probably akin to amazon's "You may like these items because you purchased these other items" feature.

### The new query

We want 1 row per insanlyBigTable.catalog_id, based on which catalog_id exists in smallerTable1, after filtering.

```
SELECT 
    ibt.description_short, 
    ibt.id AS insanlyBigTable, 
    ibt.type AS insanlyBigTableLol, 
    (
        SELECT smallerTable1.id FROM smallerTable1 st
        WHERE st.buyer_id = 'xxx' 
        AND st.cont = 'Y'
        AND st.catalog_id = ibt.catalog_id
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS catalogpartner_id
FROM insanlyBigTable ibt
WHERE ibt.id IN (
    SELECT (
        SELECT ibt.id AS ibt_id
        FROM insanlyBigTable ibt
        WHERE ibt.catalog_id = sti.catalog_id
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS ibt_id
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT(catalog_id) FROM smallerTable1 st
        WHERE st.buyer_id = 'xxx'
        AND st.cont = 'Y'
        AND EXISTS (
            SELECT * FROM insanlyBigTable ibt
            WHERE ibt.type IN ('111','222','33')
            AND ibt.catalog_id = st.catalog_id
        )
    ) AS sti
)
```

This query should generate the same result as your original query, but it breaks things down into smaller queries to avoid the use (and abuse) of the GROUP BY clause on the `insanlyBigTable`.

Give it a try and let me know if you run into problems.

Comment: Sadly i cant modify the old code to do that thing. But your query is superb :D thy!